# Render function is not called

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-component

I am trying to get my react component to render in Meteor. I don't see any error messages or anything in the console, however, the component doesn't seem to display.

I am using `react-router`. I added log statements and it appears that the renderRoutes() function does get called, also, I see errors in the console when I change the directories for my `imports` (I get an error if I change the first import statement to `import {Home} from '../home/blah'`). I am not really sure what to try next.

Here is my router, which is in `client/imports/lib/router.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

import {Home} from '../home/home';
import {Login} from '../login/login';
import {Connect} from '../connect/connect';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route exact path="/connect" component={Connect}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Here is my home page. The other pages have a similar structure. The home page is in `client/imports/home/home.js`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div><h1>hello from the home page</h1></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, this is my main.js. It's in `client/main.js`.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from './imports/lib/router.js';
import './main.html';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Again, I don't see any error messages. The home page just doesn't render. I put console.log's in the constructor for the Home component and I do not see anything. I'm not sure if there is something about React that I am not understanding or if I need to change the way I am using the router.

Please let me know what I should try next, and if there is any more information I should include.

Thanks!

Comment: `import Home from ` ?

Comment: Maybe `render(renderRoutes(), ...)` is a problem. Have you tried to use ` render(<RenderRoutes />,...)` - change casing to have it as component.

Comment: Another issue, perhaps unrelated to your bug: `Home`'s constructor function has an argument `props` and it should call `super(props)`, not `super()`.

Comment: @xadm Getting rid of the brackets around the component in the import statement did the trick. Can you post your answer below so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're exporting component using `export default`

> `export default class Home extends Component {`

then you should import it this way:

```
import Home from '../home/home';
```

Read more about [named and default exports](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#an-overview-of-the-es6-module-syntax)

---

For the future - back to the source, check original code (from [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-react-router)) first (usually working) - it's not hard to see the difference ;)